How to reorder commits in TortoiseGit rebase dialog using keys?
Especially with a larger list of commits, I sometimes lose track of where to place a commit when scrolling during tracking a commit to its new place. I thought it would be much more accurate if it were possible to move a commit using keyboard shortcuts instead of dragging it with the mouse.
Is there a way to move commits using the keyboard?
Edit:
Up & down-arrow-keys do not work (for me)(anymore).

Any ideas on the downvotes?

The close vote is clearly wrong "Not about programming or software development - Use this close reason if the question is not about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers." TortoiseGit is a software tools primarily used by programmers.

Rebase dialog supports a number of commands, just try bashing the keyboard!
U - moves selected commit(s) up
D - moves selected commit(s) down
Other commands also match their first letters: Edit, Pick, Squash.

And of course you have Ctrl/Shift/Space for adjusting selection to select several items at once.
